# Getting the class name of a JSON object sent from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I have a script in PHP that loads a user's actions on the site and is queried from AngularJS using the `$http` service via. `POST` method.

The `json_encoding` is fairly simple and doesn't use the `interface JsonSerializable` and just uses `json_encode($object, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`. However, when displaying the actions on the page, I need to be able to know what classes the actions are. My action classes are something like this:

```
class PostComment extends Action{};
class PostThread extends Action{};
```

However, in the JSON data I send from PHP, I don't see where classes are sent in PHP, (I think all the JSON data is under some general class similar to `StdClass`?). Other than assigning an attribute `$this->type` and figuring on the class from that, how can I get the class of the JSON object sent from PHP (using Javascript or some `angular.` method)

Comment: there is no general class for json serialization

Comment: Oh, you're right, I can add the class name in the jsonSerialize method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, there is no classes in JSON. Just add the name of class to your JSON with any name you like and use it in front-end.
So it will be something like this:

```
//php code
$object->className = 'MyClass';
```

will produce

```
  {
     "className":"MyClass",
     "blabla":"foo",
     ....
  }
```

Comment: well php code should be something like `$this->className = get_class($this);` inside initialization method. It will be more flexible. And please don`t make $this->className public property

Comment: I think even better is to `implement JsonSerializable` and then specify some method to return the proper array for json encoding and in the `jsonSerialize` method, specify the class name with something like `$this->className = get_class($this);`